# In the space $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, prove $(0, 1)$ is not homeomorphic to $(1,3) ∪ (5,7)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I would like general feedback on my solution to this exercise, as well as any ideas for a more direct approach.

### Exercise

In the space $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, prove $(0, 1)$ is not homeomorphic to $(1,3) ∪ (5,7)$.

### Solution

Assume otherwise, and denote by $f:(0,1)\to (1,3) ∪ (5,7)$ a bijective function such that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

By the continuity of $f$ we must have that $U:=f^{-1}((1,3))$ and $V:=f^{-1}((5,7))$ are open.

Clearly $U$ and $V$ are disjoint because so are $(1,3)$ and $(5,7)$.

Also, $U$ and $V$ are each non-empty because $f$ is onto.

So $(0,1)=U\cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are each non-empty and disjoint.

So $(0,1)$ is disconnected, which is a contradiction.

The initial assumption must have been false.

Comment: Yes, this works, assuming you are allowed to use the nontrivial fact that $(0,1)$ is connected.

Comment: It's worth noting that some essential "completeness" property of $\mathbb{R}$ must be used (here connectedness), because in $\mathbb{Q}$ with the standard topology, $(0,1)$ *is* homeomorphic to $(1,3) \cup (5,7)$.